# How can I install a generated inf file without NI VISA Driver Wizard?

Tags: labview

I'm trying to install the VISA driver for my usb device using "NI VISA Driver Wizard" if I  install the inf file created by "NI VISA Driver Wizard" using NI VISA Driver Wizard itself ,everything is ok and the driver installs correctly.

but installing the inf file manually ( right clicking >  install ) doesn't work, and windows still finds my device as a hid device and doesn't load the new driver .

I want to know how to programmatically and correctly installing the driver using LabView programming ? and also want to know why manual installation of the driver doesn't load it for my device ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you installing as an Admin? What version of Windows?  
If you go to Device Manager and Update Driver Software on your USB device and point to your INF, does it install properly then?  This Help doc on USB VISA control installation might help point you in the right path. Read the section titled ["Install the INF files and USB device"](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/4478/en/)

Comment: I'm admin and using win 7 . I have seen that link before and also can install the driver through Device Manager and Update Driver Software . as I said before I want to install it using my written program in Labview . I can install the inf file by running dos commands through Labview but windows does not automatically assign it to my device . I don't want the user try to install the driver himself.

Comment: [You're likely going to have to use the Application Builder.](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000PAhkSAG)  

I'm not really sure how it would be done with LV code but I'd bet someone could figure it out. For now though, if this is something you're deploying I think it makes the most sense to implement it via Applicaiton Builder.